# How to preserve html control interaction while having svg objects on top them?

Tags: asp.net, svg, raphael

I have a SVG canvas that should enable me to render tool on my web form, like protractor.
If I render SVG canvas on top of the form manipulating z-index property I can not access my form controls, if I render SVG behind the form I can not access my SVG object once it's gone from visible area. Here are the pictures:

[image]

[image]

Hopefully problem is described sufficiently, desirable solution would be to block form controls if SVG object is sitting exactly on top of the control.

Any help appreciated.

P.S. Just found out that page behaves as desired on IE 10 ?!

Comment: SVG allows for embedding html by means of the `foreignObject` Tag, have you Explored this possibility? More specific help will be Hard to Provide without specific Code and Markup ...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need SVG to have any interactivity (click, mouseover) then just add this CSS rule for your svg container:

```
#your-svg-container-id {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

SVG will become "transparent" for mouse pointer and you can safely put it over your form.